# Is there a better way to get dynamic CSS settings into a WP page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a plugin where I need some of the colors to be settable in the admin.

Right now, I have these color settings saved with the WP update_option() function. Then, when I need to display a page, I use the get_option() function then embed the color codes like this:

```
<style>
     .some_class{ background-color: <?php echo $settings->color_code;?>; }
</style>
```

Of course, this works. But it seems a bit clumsy because the plugin can load one of several PHP based pages. So, for each one, I have to do the above.

Is there some way to get this  tag into all my plugins pages without doing it page by page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for frontend:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_css', 100 );

function custom_css(){

    echo '<style>css here!</style>';
}
```

it should print after your current css stylesheets so it will override prev. css

Comment: Yes, of course, a hook. I really should remember to look at these things first when I have a WP issue. Thanks.